# FireFox save to PDF background image poor quality

Tags: html, pdf, firefox, background-image

No libraries, no server side. Just html. The page contains background image:

```
style="background: url('images/header_bg.png') center center; background-size: cover;"
```

When I save this page to PDF via Mozilla FireFox the quality of any background image is very poor (blurry), although images placed by `<img>` tags are OK. If I save an html page to PDF via MS Edge everything is OK with background images.

How to make good quality of background images when saving to PDF in FireFox?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a know bug without a solution yet.

https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1679514

There is a workaround of print the page enabling the background images instead of use save as pdf.

> Steps to reproduce
>
> Go to https://www.htmldog.com/examples/pullquotes2.html
>
> Print preview the page.
>
> Enable the "Print backgrounds" option.

Comment: Thanks! I also figured out: (in Windows) press CTRL+P and choose "Microsoft Print to PDF" instead of "Save to PDF"